# Is there a way to set transparency of windows in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, window, transparency

Sometimes ago I used KDE 3.5 I think, and really liked the transparency option for windows, which gave all my text editor a really killer look and feel, really nice/ethereal environment for coding.

I haven't managed to find such a possibility with GNOME.

Any idea if it is possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your system is able handle the `Opacify` compiz plugin then you just have to install [Advanced Desktop Effects Settings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and play with the `Opacify` settings till you get your desired effect.

To start the CompizConfig Settings Manager you go to **System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager**

Comment: I managed to install it, but didn't manage to find what to configure so has transparency takes effect ;-) There's an increase and decrease parameter which is certainly about opacity but dont know what sort of control it is. I'll look at it...

Comment: I have tried configuring the opacity with "class=Gedit" and window opacity value at 50... but my Gedit windows remain still plain opaque... maybe I should restart, but I have 20 windows openned,so I'll restart later... we'll see

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, and was actually planned as a feature in ubuntu (possibly may come in Natty+1 or +2 if the bugs are fixed). It is not supported however, and you may find some applications crash, misbehave, and throw tantrums and chairs.

Here is a link to the instructions: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/RGBA+Gtk%2B+module?content=100556